# angularJS -Change in variable visible between html links

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code:

```
<li ng-repeat="objekt in driversList" class="mix {{objekt.Objekt.Type}}">
  <a href="objekttest.html"  data-ajax="false"
     ng-click="objekt.Objekt.Active='yes'">
    <img ng-src="../images/thumbs/{{objekt.Objekt.Thumb}}.jpg"
         style="margin-right:0;" >
    <span id="list">{{objekt.Objekt.Name}}{{objekt.Objekt.Active}}</span>
    <span id="listmala">{{objekt.Objekt.Type}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

`objekt.Objekt.Active` changes when I click the corresponding `<li>` tag.

However, on the other HTML link, I have:

```
<div ng-repeat="objekt in driversList">
  {{objekt.Objekt.Name}} {{objekt.Objekt.Active}}
</div>
```

This time, `objekt.Objekt.Active` keeps the default value (i.e. 'no').

Is it possible to change a scope variable permanently so that it is changed on some other HTML element?

Here's my controller code:

```
angular.module('aki', [
        'aki.controllers'
    ]);

    angular.module('aki.controllers', []).
    controller('akicontroller', function($scope,$rootScope) {
    //$scope.toggle = function(){
        //$scope.driversList.
    //}
    $rootScope.active='da';
    $scope.driversList = [
      {
          Objekt: {
              Name: 'Saint & Sinner',
              Type: 'nightclub',
              Thumb: 'Sinner',
              Active:'no'         
          }
      },
      {
          Objekt: {
              Name: 'Corner Cafe',
              Type: 'cafe',
              Thumb: 'corner caffe',
              Active:'no'
          }
      },...
...
```

EDIT: I'm making multipage application without Ajax

Comment: Your `ng-click` should use a function in `$scope` to set the original object's value. `ng-click="setActive($index)"` otherwise you're only changing the value within the subscope created by `ng-repeat`.

Comment: so if I have a function, variable will be also changed on the other html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without using some form of backend or storage.

Looking at your code, you appear to have hard coded the driversList into the .js file. You're also navigating to a new page, it appears. AngularJS doesn't edit that JS file, so that's not going to persist.

You'll need to either have a backend service that stores the state (in memory or database) via http request, have AngularJS not actually change location (putting all of this on the same page, and show/hiding it as you interact), or use something like HTMLStorage to save/load the data.

You can also use something like AngularJS's Firebase backend to serve as persistence for the data - https://www.firebase.com/quickstart/angularjs.html has a quick start guide.

Comment: @Axon if you just need to store values across route changes a simple [AngularJS service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) will do (as services are singletons).

Comment: Will Services persist data across page loads? They might be singletons, and thus good for persisting across controllers, but if you are completely loading a new page, it should be reloading the service from scratch every time, wouldn't it?

Comment: That's right. It will not survive an enforced page reload (e.g. hitting the reload button). But in SPAs page reloads are very uncommon. When the user clicks on a link it does not result in a page reload but just a route change (which a service would survive).

Comment: but i use multi page app and i'm loading new page html with the same controller.Link is without AJAX

Comment: @Axon AngularJS is really made for SPAs, so a lot of people assume that. You'll find it helps to clarify for any future questions.